# Children's book about a man and a woman (a boy and a girl?) on a mountain with a dragon

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel, dragons

This is a childhood memory viewed dimly decades later. I am pretty sure that I read it before 1990, and the odds are decent that it was written before that because it was a book either we or my grandmother had in the house. It was written in English, with illustrations on each page. Being a young child's book (probably less than 20 pages) there wasn't a lot of subtlety to it. There was a woman (or maybe a girl) who lived on a mountain-top, who had a house and a garden, if not a farm. I remember a scene where she was filling a metal bucket from a pump. A (Western style) dragon starts to menace her. Fortunately, a very tough and mean man (or boy) lived on the other side of the mountain and he came and beat the dragon (I want to say that it showed him taking it down with one punch), and then the two of them lived happily ever after.

The ambiguity of age is that I remember them being spoken of as adults, but the illustrations were of two black children. I remember the girl as being dressed pretty conservatively, in a full-length dress. I think the boy was wearing a shirt and pants (although with further attempts to plumb my memory, I also has an image of him being dressed in just overalls, with only one strap on), and was bald.

I know it's not a ton to work on. I remember peas being grown in the garden, although I don't remember if they were relevant to the plot.

Comment: The most frustrating bit is that I have a few clear mental images, but I have no artistic talent.

Comment: Check out the listing of dragon books at https://www.whatdowedoallday.com/favorite-dragon-picture-and-chapter-books/.  Maybe that'll have it.  "My Father's Dragon" has a front cover that vaguely fits your description, even though the snippet of description doesn't.

Comment: @computercarguy: I've read "My Father's Dragon" (and the sequels) and that's not it. But I will take a look at that list.

Comment: I put my sister who is a children's librarian on it.  She suggested *Dragon Mountain* by Tim Vyner and *The Funny Thing* by Wanda Gag

Comment: @eshier: Thank you for the thought, but it does not match up. It was a European dragon, not a Chinese dragon, and neither book's artstyle matches. But thank you, and please thank your sister for me.

Comment: What color was the dragon?

Comment: @neodarwin: Excellent question. I don't know for certain, but my immediate gut reaction is green.

Comment: I checked at my Grandpa's and could not find the book. :(

Comment: There's also Dragon Mountain by Hans Baumann, not exact match but just in case.

Comment: @Ayche: I found some images of the inside, and it is not a match. Sorry.

Comment: Could it be Bill Peet's *How Droofus the Dragon Lost His Head*? Doesn't match description other than two children. Kids are in long clothing. It has knights coming to kill the dragon and a king who wants the dragon's head on the wall.

Comment: @bob1: Thank you for the suggestion, but the illustrations don't match.